# Stack overflow error while creating a Binary-Tree using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree, b-tree

I've been asked to create a binary tree using recursion.
Each Node has an 80% probability to have a left-son and 90% to have a right-son.
I also use random data keys.
I'm having trouble with this recursion and also quite hard debugging that.
Any idea what might be the problem?

```
void BinaryTree::createTree()
{
    if (!this->m_root)
    {
        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        this->m_root = new Node(rand() % (200) + 1);
        addRandomNodes(this->m_root);
    }

}

void BinaryTree::addRandomNodes(Node* n)
{
    if (!n)
        return;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int xL = rand() % (80) + 1;
    int yR = rand() % (90) + 1;

    //set Left-Son Recursively
    if (xL > 10) {
        Node* newLeft = new Node(rand() % (200) + 1);
        n->setLeft(newLeft);
        addRandomNodes(newLeft);
    }

    //set Right-Son Recursively
    if (yR > 10) {
        Node* newRight = new Node(rand() % (200) + 1);
        n->setRight(newRight);
        addRandomNodes(newRight);
    }

    return;

}


Node::Node() : m_left(nullptr), m_right(nullptr), m_data(0){}

Node::Node(int data) : m_left(nullptr), m_right(nullptr)
{
    this->m_data = data;
}
```

Comment: Think about how often it happens that you pass a null pointer to `addRandomNodes` and definitely exit the recursion.

Comment: You haven't described the *"trouble"* you're having, but it might have to do with the fact that the tree has only a small chance of converging; the number of nodes will usually be infinite.

Comment: You could add a max depth and end the recursion once that is reached.

Comment: So it only has to do with the probability?

Comment: Side note: normally `srand` is called only once - perhaps in `main`. But modern C++ has more robust random generators than the old `rand`. [Pseudo-random number generation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: You actually have a 7/8 chance of a left child and a 8/9 chance of a right one.  That means that the probability that you don't recurse at all is 1/8 * 1/9 = 1/72, which is less than 1.4%. Since the first condition always is false, you almost always recurse.

Comment: That is probably made much worse by the improper seeding inside the recursive calls which causes the random number generator to return the same random sequence for all calls inside of a second.

Comment: thank you for your help!